# How to make component that is shareable between different micro services and install all dependencies automatically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm working on project with 15 different micro services (10 are fronted reactjs micro services). Now I must make component that is same and usable(chat) in few micro services.

So I need some component that use another node moduls. how to build it? Make export, and import in  micro services.

Comment: take a look at https://blog.nrwl.io/, it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at publishing to a private NPM repo and consuming it into each of your microservices / micro apps

Comment: And install same modules in each micro services?  i dont want that, I want once to install